# Regex for IIS Rewrite Rules before word, and after last slash

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to work out the Regex for an IIS Rewrite rule - which should match the following URL:

> /path1/path2/staticword/dynamic/dynamic2/dynamic3/hello.css

I need it to extract the path before staticword, so 
**path1/path2/**

I then need it to match the file name 
**hello.css**

Note: this must only trigger when there is a file extension (.css |.js)

I do not need the middle section.

So far I have got this:

```
([\s\S]*)staticword([\s\S]*)(.css|.js)
```

This gets me the first part - but not the filename. I fear I need a negative look-behind - as we cannot be sure of how many paths there are.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were *very close* to the correct solution! You just needed to add a slash (/) so that the greedy [\s\S]* matcher after the staticword captures everything up to the final slash, leaving you free to capture the filename next.

Try the following regex:

```
([\s\S]*?)staticword[\s\S]*/([\s\S]*?(.css|.js))
```

It will capture the following groups:

```
match[0] = /path1/path2/staticword/dynamic/dynamic2/dynamic3/hello.css
match[1] = /path1/path2/
match[2] = hello.css
match[3] = .css
```

**Caveat:** due to the greedy matching, you will need to test one path at a time